# Hosting PHP website that uses unix command "convert" on IIS

Tags: php, imagemagick

I thought I had checked so that everything would work when hosting this website on IIS but I missed a tiny detail.
Apparantly an image upload form on the website requires a unix command or program called "convert" (usr/bin/convert) to resize, set quality and generate a thumbnail for the images. I think it's called ImageMagick.

What would be the best approach to fix this? Is there perhaps a "convert" version for Windows or equivalent? I want to avoid rewriting the upload system too much. All suggestions except moving to a unix system are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Windows version of ImageMagick:

ftp://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/imagemagick/windows/ (or use any one of the other mirrors)

You will need administrator access to install it, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can install ImageMagick on Windows

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick is available for windows as well: [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php?ImageMagick=ikiaa04c211b8tb3njog6thq27#windows)

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best approach to fix this? Is there perhaps a "convert" version for Windows or equivalent? I want to avoid rewriting the upload system too much. All suggestions except moving to a unix system are greatly appreciated.

Wouldn't you be able to simply install convert on Windows? ImageMagick (where the convert binary comes from) [has a Windows version too](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php?ImageMagick=ac524c72tr7ko3li4b8bf3met6#windows).

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed ImageMagick, they have windows binaries available on their website here: [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)